# Kotlin ORM for external database

Tags: database, kotlin, orm

I am new to Kotlin, and I'm developing an Android application that requires to query an external database, which will contain data shared between multiple users/devices.

What I want to do is exactly what is in the offical Android guide ( https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-kotlin-unit-5-pathway-2 ), but **not** with an embedded database (they use SQL Lite).

It would be great to create the ORM classes and then just use a "connection string" to find the source of data and let the app work with them.

Comment: If data needs to be shared between multiple users/devices then you probably need a server.

Comment: Of course I need it. I was thinking to something like SQL Server Management Studio. But I wonder if there is a way to make an ORM with it.

Comment: Perhaps use https://firebase.google.com/docs/database? Other "cloud DBs" are available as well from others.